# Need to verify every file passed as an argument on the command line exists using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am looking to create a shell script that reads command line arguments, then concatenates the contents of those files and print it to stdout. I need to verify the files passed to the command line exist.

I have written some code so far, but the script only works if only one command line argument is passed. If passing more than one argument, the error checking I have tried does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
echo -e "Usage: concat FILE ... \nDescription: Concatenates FILE(s) 
to standard output separating them with divider -----."
exit 1
fi

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ ! -e $@ ]]; then
            echo "One or more files does not exist"
            exit 1
    fi
done


for var in "$@"
do
    if [ -f $var ]; then
            cat $var
            echo "-----"
            exit 0
    fi
done
```

I need to fix the error checking on this so that every command line argument is checked to be an existing file. If a file does not exist, the error must be printed to stderr and nothing should be printed to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in line 11:

```
if [[ ! -e $@ ]]; then
```

You do need to check for a given file here using `$var` like that:

```
if [[ ! -e "$var" ]]; then
```

And you exit prematurely in line 23 - you will always print only a
single file. And remember to always quote your variable because
otherwise your script would not run correctly on files that have a whitespaces in the name, for example:

```
$ echo a line > 'a b'
$ cat 'a b'
a line
$ ./concat.sh 'a b'
cat: a: No such file or directory
cat: b: No such file or directory
-----.
```

You said:

> if a file does not exist, the error must be printed to stderr and
>   nothing should be printed to stdout.

You aren't printing anything to stderr at the moment, if you want to
you should do:

```
echo ... >&2
```

And you should use `printf` instead of `echo` as it's more portable
even though you're using `Bash`.

All in all, your script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "Usage: concat FILE ... \nDescription: Concatenates FILE(s) to standard output separating them with divider -----.\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ ! -e "$var" ]]; then
            printf "One or more files does not exist\n" >&2
            exit 1
    fi
done

for var in "$@"
do
    if [ -f "$var" ]; then
            cat "$var"
            printf -- "-----\n"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It is really helping me out. One thing i am noticing though is that if I pass an argument for a file that doesn't exist, it still prints the "-----" which I want it to just print the error and close instead. So for instance if i run ./concat pipes.txt pipes2.txt and only one of those exists, it will print two lines of "---" in a row

Comment: In the case where there is output to both stdout and stderr i would also like to implement an exit code 2. any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: `One thing i am noticing though is that if I pass an argument for a file that doesn't exist, it still prints the "-----" which I want it to just print the error and close instead.` - I don't observe this behavior. It says `One or more files does not exist` and exits.

Comment: `In the case where there is output to both stdout and stderr i would also like to implement an exit code 2. any ideas on how this can be done?` - I don't get it, the script does not output to both stdout and stderr at the same time. Each time it prints something to stderr it exits immediately.